# Múltiplos delimitadores no PHP dá erro, no PHPMyAdmin não

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma QUERY com vários delimitadores para executar apenas uma vez e realizar `UPDATE` em diferentes tabelas, porém dá erro de sintaxe quando executado no PHP, **mas no PHPMyAdmin funciona normalmente.**

Já verifiquei as permissões de usuários e está com as devidas.

```
UPDATE 
  `fin_dry1`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';
UPDATE 
  `fin_dry2`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';
UPDATE 
  `fin_dry3`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE `fin_dry2` SET `dr_sta.

Descobri o uso de multi_query, então alterei o [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) para [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php) e aparece outro erro:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

**Sobre o MySQL server versio**n

Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket.

Tipo de servidor: Percona Server.

Conexão com o servidor: SSL is not being used Documentação.

Versão do servidor: 5.6.41-84.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, Revision b308619.

Versão do protocolo: 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o Mysqli, você pode utilizar o comando mysqli_multi_query(). Você deve passar as queries separadas por ponto e vírgula. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = "SELECT Lastname FROM Persons ORDER BY LastName;";
$sql .= "SELECT Country FROM Customers";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
        }
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Strict Standards: mysqli_next_result(): There is no next result set.

Comment: Alterei mysqli_next_result() por mysqli_more_results() mas ficou lento, quase 15 segundos para executar.

Comment: Estou me orientando pelo link, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema com a ajuda da resposta de cima feita por @Bins, com algumas alterações devido à mensagens de erros com `"Strict Standards"` que a solução do companheiro apresentava, segue a solução em procedural.

Alterei o código que usava [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) por [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php).

```
$sql = "UPDATE 
  `fin_dry1`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';
UPDATE 
  `fin_dry2`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';
UPDATE 
  `fin_dry3`
SET
  `dr_status` = 'P' 
WHERE 
  `dr_token` = '894613';"


if(mysqli_multi_query($dbconn,$sql)){
    do{
        $cumulative_rows+=mysqli_affected_rows($dbconn);
    } while(mysqli_more_results($dbconn) && mysqli_next_result($dbconn));
}
if (mysqli_error($dbconn)) {
    printf("Erro! Houve uma exceção.");
    exit();
}
```